# html - Automatic zoom to different monitor sizes

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I've been wondering if there was a way to change the zoom on an html webpage according to the monitor size. For example, a 500px by 500px image would look big on a laptop although a monitor for a PC would make it look small. Is there possible solution I can make so that the picture scales in size as the monitor size changes?
Also, I would like the screen to just zoom not change in pixels.

Thanks!

Comment: this is called responsive design, you can use boostratp which is very good and easy to use (class : `.img-responsive`)

Comment: @singebatteur What happens if you want to do this to another element, such as canvas?

Comment: I dont know about canvas, but for 'classic' elements you just have to set a relative width for example 50%, and it will be 50% of 500px, 50% of 1920px ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `%` instead of `px` to set the size of the image.

> In HTML 4.01, the width could be defined in pixels or in % of the containing element. In HTML5, the value must be in pixels.

source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp

Or in CSS you could use Media Queries to have different style depending on the device used.

Comment: How would I change the size dynamically, like when you change the window size?

Comment: if the size is set as a percentage, any modification of the size of the container would modifies it proportionally.
For the media Queries, I invite you to read :  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I meant zoom, not the size of the image.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what does zoom means for you then... 'To zoom in' means to make an image bigger. Do you mean that you want to zoom on some detail of the image ? Or that you want to zoom when the user make a specific action ?

Comment: I just want the page to automatically zoom in so that the proportions on different sized monitors is the same.

Comment: The you can use `%`. It will keep the element proportional to its container, if the container is the body, the element will be proportional to the windows size.
Obviously, if the screen is really small the image will be very small.

Comment: I still want a set pixel size though

Comment: Also, % will affect how offset works so I just want page zoom not %